# Пути файлов в PHP

Tags: php, path

**Проблема вот в чем.**
У меня создана база данных в `OpenServer`. Создан домен с названием `social` и указан путь домена: `C:\OpenServer\domains\social`.

---

Если я использую `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` в файле `index.php` (`include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/database.php';`) и запускаю в `PHPStorm 2017.1.4`, то почему-то не работает `login.php`.

---

И как-то он странно открывается, вот его `url`: `http://localhost:63342/social/index.php?_ijt=gmbou3aiqtne3eabi82ecma3re`.
Но, если я просто в адресной строке пишу: `http://social/`, то `login.php` работает. Я так понял, проблема в файле `common.js`:
 `$.ajax({
   url: "././includes/login.php", 
   ...`

---

**Дерево проекта:**

```
social  
     |-- index.php  
     |-- register.php  
     |-- database.php  
     |
     |-- css  
     |   |-- style.css  
     |   |-- bootstrap.min.css   
     | 
     |-- js  
     |   |-- common.js  
     |
     |-- includes  
         |-- header.php 
         |-- footer.php
         |-- login.php
         |-- error   
             |-- 404.php
```

---

Как подключить
`style.css, bootstrap.min.css к header.php`,
`common.js к footer.php`
`header.php, footer.php к index.php и прочим`?

Иногда выдает такое: `Not allowed to load local resource:` или `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.

---

### Как мне подключить стили и другие файлы, что бы я потом без проблем мог закинуть сайт на хостинг?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `include` (и в других функциях) можно и нужно использовать относительные пути:

```
include_once ('database.php');
include_once ('../database.php');
```

и т.д.
Если нужны полные пути, то смотри, не выдает ли `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` слеш в конце. И опять же, в Винде слеши ''\'', а ты используешь ''/''.

Comment: А стили как предлагаете подключать?

Comment: Стили прописываются в HTML. В PHP можно HTML код прописывать либо через echo, либо за рамками тегов <?php ?>